# Button positioned incorrectly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

So in Google Chrome, sometimes the button shows in the correct place, and if you refresh the same page again it will show in the wrong place (Also the other way around). It works fine in all other browsers:

**This is a Chrome specific issue**

```css
#paypal {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div id="paypal">
  <h2>Donate!</h2>
  <script async="async" src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant="email@email.com' data-button="donate " data-name="PayPal " data-currency="USD " data-callback="website ">
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: is this the only item in the html?

Comment: Learn the difference between "display", "float" and "position" and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use position relative to the parent div and apply css like this:

```
#paypal{
 /*display: inline;
   float: right;
   no need to use float or display as you're using absolute positioning*/
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-right: 30px;
   position: absolute;
 /* you can define top,right...*/
}
```